# Check in every controller, can it be converted in reusable module?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on angular app which has around 3-4 controllers. on each controller I need to check several things like authentication / compatible browsers and redirect to error controller. Right now, I have a code block at start of every controller..

I have UI router in place.. This is the code block at start of every controller.

Help me with best possible way to make this code modular..

```
if (is.ios() || is.windowsPhone()) {
            $scope.errorLog = {
                'message': 'This app is not compatible with the browser you are using',
                'time': new Date()
            };
            $state.go('error', {
                errorLog: $scope.errorLog
            });

            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `is` is a service or a factory. You also mentioned that you use UI router which makes the task pretty easy.

```js
.state('onlyAndroidandWindows', {
  url: '/hateiphone',
  platforms: ['android', 'windows'] //add this to state where platform needs to be checked
});
```

Then at run stage insert route change listener

```js
  app.run(function($rootScope, $state, is) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
      var currentPlatform = is.currentPlatform();
      var allowedPlatforms = (next.platforms) ? next.platforms :    is.allPlatforms();
      if (allowedPlatforms.indexOf(currentPlatform) === -1) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var errorLog = {
            'message': 'This app is not compatible with the browser you are using',
            'time': new Date()
        };
        $state.go('error', {
            errorLog: errorLog
        });
      }
    });
    ...
```